# Lagging when mouse position updated?

Tags: python, pygame

I've been using pygame to create a pretty basic game just to experiment with, and I recently have encountered some lag. Whenever I add this code:

```
if exitcode==0:
            pygame.font.init()
            font = pygame.font.Font(None, 24)
            text = font.render("Accuracy: "+str(accuracy)+"%", True, (255,0,0))
            textRect = text.get_rect()
            textRect.centerx = screen.get_rect().centerx
            textRect.centery = screen.get_rect().centery+24
            screen.blit(gameover, (0,0))
            screen.blit(text, textRect)
        else:
            pygame.font.init()
            font = pygame.font.Font(None, 24)
            text = font.render("Accuracy: "+str(accuracy)+"%", True, (0,255,0))
            textRect = text.get_rect()
            textRect.centerx = screen.get_rect().centerx
            textRect.centery = screen.get_rect().centery+24
            screen.blit(youwin, (0,0))
            screen.blit(text, textRect)
```

It lags. I thought it might be because of my `while` loops, but that wasn't it. Can anyone tell me the source of my lag? I can post other codes from my game if you need. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Don't call `pygame.font.init()` or create a new `Font` object in your mainloop, since this costs lot of time.

If you already call `pygame.init()`, you don't need `pygame.font.init()` at all.

For your `Font` object: just create it *once* outside your mainloop.

Also, if you do a lot of font rendering (calling `font.render`), you should cache the resulting surfaces, since font rendering is also a quite expensive operation in pygame.